# How to hide app script from others when sharing google spreadsheet that has onEdit(e) function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Although I am new to Google Apps Script I managed to write a `onEdit(e)` function with a couple of other functions which are called using Switch Case. I googled how to hide the script from others when I share the file and it said that we could do this by creating a standalone file for the script and use the spreadsheet id like `SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID)` instead of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`. Here in my case, there is no such code. I have a onEdit(e) file and I use `e.` whenever I refer to a range/cell. Could someone help with this?

Comment: A bounded script can't be hidden from editors, instead create an add-on

Comment: @Rubén true, but onEdit() and addons don't go hand in hand in my experience

Comment: I have no idea what lead you to have that experience. In my experience onEdit works pretty well with Google Sheets add-ons

Comment: @Rubén I have created a new standalone Apps Script and put my code in it. Can you tell me what's next, please?

Comment: @Codist There are a lot of step-by-steps guides on the web. I suggest you to start looking at https://developers.google.com/apps-script. They have complete Editor add-on examples, guides, codelabs. Here are a couple of specifi links: 1) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/sheets/quickstart/attendance 2) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/clean-sheet